# WCF Self Hosted App on 64bit Windows Server

Tags: wcf, 64-bit

I have a windows application that acts as a WCF Service that I developed on a 32bit Windows Server 2008 box. I have tested the application and everything works fine when running it from my development machine, as well as from my 32bit workstation. However, when attempting to run the application on a 64bit Windows 2008 Server, the application does not run, and a Windows Error Report is generated stating that the application stopped working. I have attempted to build the application on my 32bit Development Workstation, targeting both x86 and x64, to no avail. The only time I can get the application to run is if I comment out the code that starts the WCF Service. So my question is, do I need to dev and/or build this application on a 64bit workstation to allow the application to run on a 64bit machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, nevermind...needed to run the app as admin on that server...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure http.sys to accept your urls using the httpcfg utility. There is a similar thing for Windows Server 2003.

- [How to add a URL ACL and avoid AddressAccessDeniedException in Windows Vista](http://www.casadehambone.com/HowToAddAURLACLAndAvoidAddressAccessDeniedExceptionInWindowsVista.aspx)
- [Httpcfg Examples: Internet Information Services (IIS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786389.aspx)